# How to Change focus from addressbar on new tab bar when I click on my extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser

Hello I am building my chrome extension, and when user creates a new tab focus is set to addressbar, but when he presses my extension icon which redirects him, focus is still set on addressbar(unless I clicked somewhere else) and I can't set focus anything on page. Is there some way to solve this?